# WebView.getContentHeight() always returns 0

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to display an HTML string in a WebView named webDescription. Because this HTML can sometimes be lengthy, I want to limit the height of the WebView to a maximum dimension and allow the content to scroll within the view.

I am using the following code to wait until the page finishes loading, check the content height and set the height of the enclosing (parent) TableRow to a maximum of 150.

```
    webDescription.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
            Log.i("EVENTDETAIL", "Web view has finished loading");
            Log.i("EVENTDETAIL", "Description content height: " + view.getContentHeight());
            if ( view.getContentHeight() > 150 ) {
                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 150);
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }

    });
```

However, view.getContentHeight() always returns 0; thus, the LayoutParams of the parent TableRow never get changed.

Can anyone offer any insight into this and how I might fix my problem? Thanks so much for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
 if(view.getHeight()>150) 
 {
      LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 150);
      view.setLayoutParams(params);
 }
```

I meant use `getHeight()` instead of `getContentHeight()`

Answer (score 0):

I would set the WebView to match_parent and set a maxHeight on the TableRow.